# Laravel AJAX PUT & DELETE

Tags: ajax, laravel, http-delete, http-put

On my development machine, everything works fine in regards to POST, PUT, DELETE, GET.

For example:

```
POST https://example.com/laravel/project (will create a new project - with data coming in from ajax)
PUT https://example.com/laravel/project/1 (will update the content of project with ID 1)
DELETE https://example.com/laravel/project/1 (will delete the project with ID 1)
```

However, I moved my project to production (a different server) and now

```
POST https://example.com/laravel/project (will create a new project as expected)
PUT https://example.com/laravel/project/1 (will not **update** project 1)
DELETE https://example.com/laravel/project/1 (will **not** delete project 1)
```

I have checked chrome's network tab, and I can see the cookies being present and the data that is coming in from the ajax call (for example, the fields that are updated/modified).

Also, I am getting a status 200 so there aren't any issues on webserver from what I understand too.

Examples of my ajax calls below - they are in $.ajax and have success and fail functions. just showing the important bits :)

```
type: 'POST',
url: '/laravel/project',
data: {
    '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
    'project_name': $('#project_name_add').val(),
    'category': $('#category_add').val()
}

type: 'PUT',
url: '/laravel/project/' + id,
data: {
    '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
    'project_name': $('#project_name_edit').val(),
    'category': $('#category_edit').val()
},
```

However, it is not actually updating or deleting anything.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: try adding a hidden field for that `_method` for method [spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#form-method-spoofing)

Comment: @Webinion actually, the _method is required for HTML forms, but is not required for ajax.

Comment: yes, I know, but just try with that. Also check console and see which request is being made for AJAX.

Comment: @Webinion okay, from development it is working fine with type: POST and then adding _method with PUT. Now I need to try it on the live/production server. Any ideas why it is working fine on development though?

Comment: The request shows as POST, since i changed it to POST and then used _method PUT. This is on dev server. Will reply back once I get access. Thanks.

Comment: some server have disabled specific request types.

Comment: @Webinion hmm, apache 2.4? default settings?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164279/discussion-between-webinion-and-rsk).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding a hidden field to the form named `_method`. The feature is called `method spoofing`.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#form-method-spoofing

```
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

Comment: Amazing. Tested on production server and worked a treat. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help you !! **happy coding :)**

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, using jquery:

```js
const data = {
  _method: 'PUT',
  _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}',
  ...others data here.
}
$.post(`/foo/bar`, data, function(res) {
  console.log(res);
})
```