# PUT Request does not function with Request Class in a Laravel 8.x application

Tags: php, laravel, rest, laravel-8

On a Laravel 8.x application, a PUT request does not work with the the `Standard Request` Class.

```
    save() {
        let formData = this.prepareFormInput('save');

        this.saveBeforeHook();

        axios.put(`/${this.model}/edit`, formData, this.axiosHeaders)
            .then(r => {
                if(r.data.errors) {
                    this.formDialog.errors = r.data.errors;
                } else {
                    if(r.data.record) {
                        this.saveAfterHook(r.data.record);
                    }

                    this.$root.formDialog.show = false;
                    this.$root.formMode = "add";
                }
            }).
            catch(e => {
                if(e.response.data.errors) {
                    this.formDialog.errors = e.response.data.errors;
                }
            });
    }
```

I have validated that the PUT request is sending the correct parameters:
[image]

However the request object does not correctly set any posted data. Looing at the request object, none of the data is set.

I have isolated the issue down to a `PUT` request in `Laravel 8.x`.

Using a `POST` request with the same information in `Laravel 8.x` works fine.
[image]

However the `PUT` request does not SET parameters into the Request object:
[image]

Using the same PUT request in a `Laravel 5.x` application works fine.

**Why are PUT requests not properly functioning in `Laravel 8.x`?**

Comment: Mind sharing the code that is sending the PUT request, you mentioned it's done via ajax

Comment: Sure. I just updated the content.

Comment: Do you have any middleware configured on this PUT route ?
Are you using the local PHP web server (artisan serve) or a regular web server ?

Comment: No middleware with the exception of RoleMiddleware from: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission . Using Apache 2.4.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will fix your problem
For `PUT` you want to make your form like

```
<form action="/example" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

or

```
<form action="/example" method="POST">
    @method('PUT')
    @csrf
</form>
```

For more info: [Form Method Spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#form-method-spoofing)

**EDIT:**
If you are using `ajax` then use `method` as "POST" and pass `_method` value as "PUT". For more info: [Laravel AJAX PUT & DELETE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48545894/laravel-ajax-put-delete)

Comment: This is to post form data utilizing a PUT method. I am using an ajax request.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I was having issues while testing using Postman, but then I solved it with your answer